# What is the finger technique for harmonium?

Tags: classical-music, indian-classical

I have gone through many website to learn the finger technique for harmonium.
But all they mention is the technique same as keyboard.

e.g. start from c -1 d -2 e -3 f- 1 g- 2 a- 3 b 4- c-5 ,
1 is thumb and so on.
But I know the difference. In harmonium, they don't use pinky finger.
Please if any one know the answer, please share it. It will be helpful for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Harmonium players do use all five fingers. [Here](http://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ImagefromIndex/413439) is a treatise by one of the greatest harmonium masters explicitly giving instructions to that effect.

Comment: @killian what is this link it is not working I got one pdf which is in not in english

Comment: The harmonium was invented in Europe in the 19th century, and was taken to other countries by Christian missionaries. However Indian musicians then started to use it as a drone instrument in a completely different way from its original European use. @Kilian Foth's link (in German) is about the European method of playing it, which was basically the same technique as playing a church pipe organ. This might be more useful for the OP: http://www.soundofindia.com/lessons.asp. Note, that link (lesson 4) uses all the fingers.

Comment: @alephzero In India people use only 4 finger to play harmonium